# Unable to obtain all boundary points on a convex hull using ConvexHullRegion

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

I'm using an old function which uses `ConvexHull` from the obsolete `ComputationalGeometry` package.  I understand this is superseded by `ConvexHullRegion`.  However, I need to know which points are on the lower boundary legs of the convex hull and ConvexHull returns this information.  In the plot below, the points $(0,8),(3,6),(6,4),(9,2),(12,0)$ are on the (single) lower leg of the polygon and those points are returned by ConvexHull.   But `ConvexHullRegion` only returns the vertexes of the hull.  For example, using the obsolete `ConvexHull` function:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];    
myPoints = {{0, 8}, {2, 7}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {8, 
        3}, {9, 2}, {12, 0}};
    chIndexes = ConvexHull[myPoints];
    Sort@myPoints[[chIndexes]]

    (* {{0, 8}, {2, 7}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}, {6, 4}, {8, 3}, {9, 2}, {12, 0}} *)
```

returns all 8 points on the boundary of the hull:

[image]

But if I use:

```
RegionBoundary[ConvexHullRegion[myPoints]] /. Line[x_] -> x

{{0, 8}, {12, 0}, {4, 6}, {0, 8}}
```

this is only returning the vertex points of the convex hull.

I'd prefer to switch to `ConvexHullRegion`if it's easy to do so because the obsolete ConvexHull may be removed in future revisions of Mathematica but haven't figured out how to do this but maybe missing something.  Or is there no built-in construct to do this?

Comment: Would you add something that states why you need all of boundary points as they are not needed to define the convex hull?  My point is that do you just need to know which points are on the boundary or do you really need those points included in the convex hull polygon?  That would help with how to approach an answer.

Comment: @Jim:  Ok I updated the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chr = ConvexHullRegion[myPoints];
```

You can use [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html) to select members of `myPoints` that lie on the boundary of `chr`:

```
pointsOnBoundary = Select[SignedRegionDistance[chr]@# == 0 &] @ myPoints
```

> ```
> {{0, 8}, {2, 7}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}, {6, 4}, {8, 3}, {9, 2}, {12, 0}}
> ```

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, chr, 
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point @ pointsOnBoundary, 
  Black, AbsolutePointSize[5],  Point @ myPoints},
ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

You can also use [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) + [`RegionBoundary`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBoundary.html) as follows:

```
RegionIntersection[RegionBoundary[chr], Point@myPoints][[1]] == pointsOnBoundary
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: It's pretty cool, how almost every time you write an answer, I have some new reading to do :-) (talking about [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html))

Comment: @kglr:  Thank you.  Nice to know about that function, and this definitely answers my question.  However, it is unfortunately 9400 times slower than ConvexHull in this case:  1.45s and 0.00015s respectively on my machine which would be unacceptably slow for my app which can create hundreds of hulls.  I'll leave the thread open for a few days in case anyone wants to attempt a speed improvement otherwise I'll check your excellent answer.

Comment: @josh, try `Select[SignedRegionDistance[DiscretizeRegion@RegionBoundary@chr]@#==0&]@myPoints)` for a much faster version.

Comment: @kglr:  Excellent improvement!  Down to 0.035s.   And I realize speed was not the topic of my thread.  Thanks for taking the time to propose a nice improvement.

Comment: @josh You can speed it up by not placing `SignedRegionDistance` in `Select` e.g. [extracting upper bound envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71816677/879601)

Comment: @Chris Degnen:  If I remove SignedRegionDistance, in Select as:  `Select[(DiscretizeRegion@RegionBoundary@chr)@# == 0 &]@myPoints`  I get syntax errors.

Comment: @josh I mean like this `chr = ConvexHullRegion[myPoints];
sr = SignedRegionDistance[chr];
pointsOnBoundary = Select[myPoints, sr[#] == 0 &]`